# Calories composition and weight loss

Tags: diet, weight-loss, physical-health

My question comes after having read this  [article](http://www.foxnews.com/health/2010/11/09/professor-loses-pounds-junk-food-diet.html).
Let's take a Person A and suppose the needed amount of calories for A is 2500 Kcal.
Now suppose A wants to limit the amount of daily calories to 2000 Kcal.
Given 2 diets (just as an example) of 2000 Kcal divided as follows:

- 50% from proteins, 30% from carbohydrates and 20% from fats
- 50% from fats, 30% from carbohydrates, and 20% from proteins.

Will the outcome be the same (I.e., weight loss in the same way) as stated in the article?

Ignoring the bad health effects of a diet with a wrong equilibrium how the composition does not matter if only considering weight loss?

Comment: If there is the same calorie deficit, it will be about the same weight loss, regardless of the macronutrient percentage (considering that the level of physical activity remains the same). A lot of studies about this have been published (low-carb or high-carb diet and weight loss, etc.). Different individuals may find a certain nutrient pattern easier to follow, though. And certain patterns may be healthier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Macronutrient (carbs, proteins, fats) composition of a diet does not have a significant direct effect on weight loss.**

[Comparison of Weight-Loss Diets with Different Compositions of Fat, Protein, and Carbohydrates (PubMed, 2009, a randomized clinical trial involving 811 overweight adults)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3735822/)

> Reduced-calorie diets result in clinically meaningful weight loss
>   regardless of which macronutrients they emphasize.

On the other hand, certain macronutrient compositions and forms *may* be associated with **increased satiety** (and hence lower food intake):

- Solid, compared to liquid carbs ([PubMed, 2011](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/10878689))
- Foods high in fiber, such as whole-grain pasta, compared to refined-grain pasta ([PubMed, 2016](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27496788))
- Foods high in viscous soluble fiber, such as whole-grain oats ([PubMed, 2016](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26724486))
- Low-carb, high fat diets ([PubMed, 2016](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4873405/))

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer and for the references, I'll check them out.

Comment: Also look at ACLM website for additional research, much of which is digested for public consumption

Comment: Any specific link?

Answer (score -1):

When it comes to losing weight, your eating habits and food choices matter a lot to achieve your fitness goals. You have to quit junk and unhealthy food and add healthy and nutrient-rich foods to your diet. No matter how many crunches or push-ups you can do in a day, if you will not fill your diet with healthy foods and break your unhealthy eating habits, then you are not going to maintain a healthy weight, quoting [Explore Diet](https://explorediet.co.uk/best-foods-for-weightloss/?utm_source=FWL), a UK based blog here, that "By eating healthy, it can help you lose weight but in a meaningful way.